# Regex pattern causes compilation error

Tags: c#, regex

In C# I have this regex pattern:

```
r = New Regex("^(("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*)(,("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*))*)$");
```

At the moment this is giving me this error: "CS1002: ; expected"

I understand this is most likely an escape string problem, but I can't see where it is.

Cheers for your help!

Comment: Don't you see the highlighting in your question? You forgot to escape the `"`.

Comment: You must escape the double quotes. `" => \"`

Comment: I don't have access to a decent code editor at the moment.

Comment: r = New Regex("^((\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)(,(\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*))*)$");

Comment: Hi. I still get the error even if I copy paste the corrected code directly. Could this be a configuration problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how Ahmed KRAIEM already told you you need to escape your `"` with `\`

your version:

```
r = New Regex("^(("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*)(,("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*))*)$");
```

my version

```
r = New Regex("^((\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)(,(\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*))*)$");
```

Comment: Or add @ symbol before string something like @"^(("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*)(,("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*))*)$"
Wouldn't it do the trick?

Comment: @Alex no it won'T because it's like `@"string"error"` ;-) it only works for `@"string\string"` instead of `"string\\string"`